# How to call __exit__ method on exception during __init__?

Tags: python, python-2.7

Assume you have a class with defined `__enter__` and `__exit__` methods like so:

```
class MyClass:
    def f(self):
        raise Exception
    def __enter__(self): 
        return self
    def __exit__(self, type, value, traceback):
        pass
```

If an exception is raised inside the `with` block, like so:

```
with MyClass() as ins:
    ins.f()
```

The `__exit__` method will be implicitly called, which is very nice.

However if your class is like this:

```
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self):
        self.f()
    def f(self):
        raise Exception
    def __enter__(self): 
        return self
    def __exit__(self, type, value, traceback):
        pass
```

And you instantiate it like so:

```
with MyClass() as ins:
    pass
```

When the exception is raised inside the `__init__` method, `__enter__` has yet to be called, and `__exit__` goes uncalled as well, which is not so nice. What is the best way to remedy this?

Comment: Other than catching the exception in `__init__()`?

Comment: I'm curious if I can get the nice implicit catching that goes on when the exception is raised after the object's `__enter__` has been called, hopefully avoiding an additional `try` block. Maybe just catching the exception in `__init__` is the way to go, just wondering if theres something more pythonic that avoid me having to essentially duplicate the `__exit__` method

Comment: There is no way for Python to call the `__exit__` method here; it is a method on an instance that never got a chance to complete construction. No instance, no `__exit__` method. Your only recourse is to handle the exception within `.__init__()` yourself to ensure that the instance construction completes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Obviously you cannot use a class that cannot be initiated as a context manager, so you have to create the instance before using it in the with block.

For example:

```
try:
    ins = MyClass()
except Exception as e: 
    print "Cant initiate MyClass"
else:
    with ins:
        pass
```

You can add extra resources by passing them to the Class instead of creating them during initiation:

```
with spawnResource() as res, MyClass(res) as y:
    print x,y
```

Comment: for sure, but suppose a few things have happened during initiation that i want to clean up if initiation is not successful. Ie the object opens some file handles or something. Is there any way to have a method that is called implicitly when initiation fails? I could just call `__exit__` explicitly but that seems sort of clunky to me

Comment: Switch the logic of your code and spawn the resources first and then pass them to your class. This way you can use `with` again.

Comment: ah right, that definitely sounds like a better way to approach this

Answer (score 2):

Like others pointed out, there's no clean way, because what you're attempting to do is awkward.

The straightforward way is:

> If you want something cleaned up in `__exit__`, initialise it in
>   `__enter__`.

E.g.

```
class MyClass:
    def f(self):
        raise Exception
    def __enter__(self):
        print 'in __enter__'
        # acquire it here...
        return self
    def __exit__(self, type, value, traceback):
        print 'in __exit__'
        # release it here...

with MyClass() as ins:
    print 'calling f()'
    ins.f()
```